# stop onitemselected event for spinner get activitated on orientation change of phone

Tags: android, spinner, android-orientation

I implemented a spinner in my app,and also `onItemSelected` event and is working fine.But the problem is that the event is triggered on the "orientation change" of the phone which i don't want.

here is my code for the event

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dropadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lastTime);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    final Spinner Items = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.timeScan);
    Items.setAdapter(dropadapter); 
    Items.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
            String temp = Items.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                     .show();
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            View loader = (View) findViewById(R.id.preloader);
            loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);         
            new Read().execute(7);

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

I dont want the event trigger on orientation change of phone. 
please suggest some way to solve this problem.

Comment: This is because as you change the orientation, the Android re-creates your activity. Meaning that your onCreate() method will be called again. You need to override onConfigurationChanged method, to handle orientation yourself.

Comment: can you please elaborate with an example ho to override onconfigurationchanged method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simplest Solutions :**

Open your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
        <activity
        android:name="youractivity name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

Comment: "Satya - Vachan" che bapu...! @Biraj Zalavadia